# Why is a declare-styleable necessary if you can just read from the AttributeSet directly?

Tags: android, android-xml, attr, android-custom-view, declare-styleable

I've created a custom View subclass with the following constructor:

```
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);

    // get custom "thingy" attribute specified in XML
    int thingy = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(MY_NAMESPACE, "thingy", 0);

    //rest of constructor
    ...
}
```

As can be seen, it grabs a custom "thingy" attribute from its XML attributes. This works absolutely fine, and I have had no problems so far. Why then, does Google tell you to define a custom View's XML attributes in a `declare-styleable` in `res/values/attrs.xml` (discussed [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr)) and to apply them by calling `context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes()` (discussed [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#applyattr))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm dumb. The second link I posted *does* explain why:

> When a view is created from an XML layout, all of the attributes in
>   the XML tag are read from the resource bundle and passed into the
>   view's constructor as an AttributeSet. Although it's possible to read
>   values from the AttributeSet directly, doing so has some
>   disadvantages:
>
> - Resource references within attribute values are not resolved
> - Styles are not applied
>
> Instead, pass the AttributeSet to
>   obtainStyledAttributes(). This method passes back a TypedArray array
>   of values that have already been dereferenced and styled.